# How to preload a GUI with database entry data?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, user-interface

I am trying to preload a GUI with the data of a database entry. Basically in the previous JForm I have asked the user to input a name, and this class takes that name and fills up the existing textfields and areas with the database entry, although it doesn't seem to be working as it doesn't preload any of the existing fields although it does exist in the database. If anyone could help it would be gratefully appreciated as this is due very soon!

```
  public void presetPage(){
    modifyRecipe m = new modifyRecipe();
    String name = m.getSR();
    try{
        String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Cookbook";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        String sql = "SELECT * from RECIPES where name=?";
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, name);

        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        boolean found = false;

        while(rs.next()){
            if(rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Found " + name );
                found = true;

                txtName.setText(rs.getString(1));
                txtSubcatagory.setText(rs.getString(2));
                cmbCatagory.getSelectedItem().toString();
                txtIngredients.setText(rs.getString(4));
                txtInstructions.setText(rs.getString(5));
                txtMod.setText(rs.getString(6));



            }else if(!found){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item Not Found!");
            this.dispose();

        }
        }
```

Comment: There seems to be some unnecessary code here. If you have run a query that only selects the name, there is no need to check if the data you got back is correct. You only need to know that you got a row. Also, I'm not familiar with the library - but do you need a next() to get to the first row? If not then you will be already going past the row before you check name=name.

Comment: It should be obvious that a single JTextField cannot display the names of all of your recipes.  When you want to display multiple records, typically you use a [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the [`database`](https://dbmstools.com/categories/database-documentation-tools#:%7E:text=Database%20documentation%20is%20a%20set,relationships%2C%20data%20types%2C%20etc.):

Use a [`JDBC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/) driver to connect to the database like this:

```
String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Cookbook";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

---

Prepare a `SELECT` query:

Write a `SELECT` query to get the data from [`database`](https://dbmstools.com/categories/database-documentation-tools#:%7E:text=Database%20documentation%20is%20a%20set,relationships%2C%20data%20types%2C%20etc.). Use [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to bind the parameters to the query:

```
String sql = "SELECT * from RECIPES where name=?";
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, name);
```

---

Execute the query:

Execute the query and get the [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), also check if it has any data:

```
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
  // the result set has data
} else {
  // the result set is empty
}
```

---

Load the data in [GUI](https://enrico.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gui.html):

Use data from [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) to load [GUI](https://enrico.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gui.html):

```
txtName.setText(rs.getString(1));
txtSubcatagory.setText(rs.getString(2));
cmbCatagory.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(3));
txtIngredients.setText(rs.getString(4));
txtInstructions.setText(rs.getString(5));
txtMod.setText(rs.getString(6));
```

The GUI components must be initialised before [`setText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) or [`setSelectedItem()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) methods.

GUI must be initialised either the data won't be loaded.

---

```
public void presetPage() {
  //modifyRecipe m = new modifyRecipe();
  //String name = m.getSR();
  try {
    String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Cookbook";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    String sql = "SELECT * from RECIPES where name=?";
    //PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    //pst.setString(1, name);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
      txtName.setText(rs.getString(1));
      txtSubcatagory.setText(rs.getString(2));
      cmbCatagory.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(3));
      txtIngredients.setText(rs.getString(4));
      txtInstructions.setText(rs.getString(5));
      txtMod.setText(rs.getString(6));
    } else {
      //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item Not Found!");
      //this.dispose();
    }
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

We assume the GUI comp are initialised and the SQL query returns a single row. If query returns multiple rows, you have to handle that appropriately.